# How to publish as a Page without requesting extended permissions from a user?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

1. I have one Facebook App that I only use to authenticate users on a website, get their names and profile pictures.
2. I also have a Facebook Page related to that same website.
3. My personal profile is administrator of both the App and the Page. Also the Page is registered as "App Page" in the advanced settings of the App.
4. I want to publish on the Page from a server using the Graph API and the credentials of the App without the need to ask for extended permissions such as `manage_pages` or `publish_pages` from my users because I don't need them (see point 1). I don't want to publish on *their* page, only on *mine*.

**How do I make my App "administrator" of my Page so that no additional permission is required for the App to publish on behalve of the Page?**

I know a quick and dirty solution would be to create another App that would be just used as a gateway between my profile and the Page (I would be the only user of the App, granting all the required permissions). But I would like to avoid having two different Apps.

Comment: “I don't want to publish on _their_ page, only on _mine_.” - Then you simply don’t ask _them_ for those additional permissions, but only _yourself_. Wow, that was rather obvious.

Comment: I did not know an app could ask for permissions from a restricted set of users. I thought all the permissions were to be asked from all users.

Comment: _You_ specify what permissions to ask for in your code, when you create the login URL/call FB.login/embed the login button. If you want to ask yourself for additional permissions, then you can either modify the code at that point accordingly, or you implement it somewhere else (like only accessible from your own admin backend or sth. like that.)

Comment: It is that simple... Alright, thanks I will try that out ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to publish "as Page" on your Page, you need to authorize your Facebook account with `manage_pages` and `publish_pages` and get a Page Token. That is the only way.

You can use an Extended Page Token and store it:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens
- http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-access-tokens/